# .htaccess mod_rewrite linking to wrong page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, clean-urls

I have in my .htaccess the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?([^/\.]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/?([^/\.]+).php$ $1/ [R,L]
```

`RewriteRule ^/?([^/\.]+)/?$ $1.php [L]` is working fine. What this is doing is taking a url like `http://www.example.com/whatever` and making it read the page as `http://www.example.com/whatever.php`.

However, what I'd like to be able to do is take a url like `http://www.example.com/whatever.php` and automatically send it to `http://www.example.com/whatever`, hence the second line of the code. However, this isn't working. What its doing now, is as soon as it comes across a link ending in `.php`, the url becomes `http://localhost/C:/Sites/page/whatever/`, and pulling a `403: Forbidden` page.

All I want to know is what I can to so that `http://www.example.com/whatever.php` will be read as `http://www.example.com/whatever`, and that if `http://www.example.com/whatever.php` is entered into the URL bar, it will automatically redirect to `http://www.example.com/whatever`.

Does that make any sense?

**EDIT**

Ok, so it appears I wasn't all too clear.. basically, I want `/whatever/` to read as `whatever.php` while the URL still stays as `/whatever/`, right? However, if the URL was `/whatever.php`, I want it to actually *redirect* the users URL to `/whatever/`, and then once again read it as `whatever.php`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're rules are inside an .htaccess file, you can omit the leading slash when you match against a URI:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Also note that a leading slash is included in the target (`/$1.php`), this makes sure **/whatever/** gets rewritten to **/whatever.php**. When you redirect, if you are missing this leading slash, apache prepends the document root to it. Thus **/whatever.php** gets redirected to the document root **C:/Sites/page/whatever/**. Even if you include the leading slash, this will never work because you're going to cause a redirect loop:

1. Enter "http://www.example.com/whatever.php" in your address bar
2. apache redirects you to "http://www.example.com/whatever/"
3. apache gets the URI **whatever/** and applies the first rule and the URI gets rewritten to **/whatever.php**
4. The URI gets put through the rewrite engine again
5. the URI **/whatever.php** matches the second rule and redirects the browser to "http://www.example.com/whatever/"
6. repeat steps 3-5

You need to add a condition that the *actual request* is for **/whatever.php**:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST|HEAD)\ /([^/\.]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^ /%2/ [R,L]
```

So altogether, you'll have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ /$1.php [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST|HEAD)\ /([^/\.]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^ /%2/ [R,L]
```

Comment: Thanks Jon! I tried this code earlier, and it didn't seem to work, but I tried it again this morning, and what do you know, it works! It appears my `.htaccess` was simply having a moment.. still, thank you very much for this!

Answer (score 0):

You're making a relative path substitution in a per-directory context (`.htaccess` is a per-directory context). This requires `RewriteBase`. Per-directory rewrites are done in a later stage of processing, when URLs have been mapped to paths. But the rewrite must produce a URL, which is processed again. I think without the `RewriteBase` to supply the URL prefix, you end up with a filesystem prefix instead of the URL. That may be why you're getting the `C:/Sites` thing. Try `RewriteBase`.  But after a correct `RewriteBase` to specify the correct URL prefix to be tacked in front to the relative rewritten part, I'm afraid you will have the rewrite loop, because you're rewriting `whatever.php` to `whatever`; and `whatever` to `whatever.php`.

Reference: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html

Comment: Cheers Kaz, I think this could make a big difference. However, I'm not _redirecting_ `whatever` to `whatever.php` so much, I thought, as just telling it when it sees `whatever`, to draw information from `whatever.php`. Is there any way I can do it so that if it sees `whatever` it will draw from `whatever.php`, but the url will still show `whatever`, but if the url is `whatever.php`, it will redirect to `whatever`?